# Let $T:P_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\rightarrow P_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ be the linear map defined by $T(P(x))=x^2P’’(x)$. Create the map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I haven't learned to create a map using a derivative, how would I do that (sorry if its a stupid question).

> $T:P_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\rightarrow P_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is defined for $P \in P_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right) $ by $T(P(x))=x^2P’’(x)$

Comment: What does 'create the map' mean?

Comment: I also see that you asked some questions during the last few days. If one of the answers given helped you out, please accept it. This marks the question as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then $p''(x)=6ax+2b$, hence $x^2p''(x)=6ax^3+2bx^2.$

Thus

$$T(p)(x)=6ax^3+2bx^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$

Then you have $P’(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$ and $P’’(x)=6ax+2b$

Then $T(P(x))=x^2P’’(x)=x^2(6ax+2b)=6ax^3+2bx^2$ which is in $P_3(\mathbb{R}) $

You can note that for any polynomial having a degree lower or equal to $1$ the image is zero hence $Ker(T)=P_1(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 0):

A basis of $\operatorname{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is given by the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. The map is completely defined by the images of these basisvectors. We obtain that 
\begin{align*}
T(1) &= 0\\
T(x) &= 0\\
T(x^2) &= 2x^2\\
T(x^3) &= 6x^3
\end{align*}

In this basis, a general polynomial $d + cx + bx^2 + ax^3$ has coordinates $(d,c,b,a)$. The map is determined by the images of these basisvectors. Gathering the coordinates of the images with respect to the given basis, we find the following matrix (put the coordinates of the image of the first basis vector in the first column, and so on):
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6
\end{pmatrix}

We then find the coordinates of image of a general polynomial by multiplying the matrix with the coordinates :
$$T(d + cx + dx^2 + ax^3) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} d\\c\\b\\a\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 2b \\ 6a\end{pmatrix}.$$

We hence find that $T(d + cx + bx^2 + ax^3) = 2bx^2 + 6ax^3$, which agrees with the other answers. This shows how you find the matrix associated with this linear map and how to use it.